# Access data in structures when field names are unknown

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I have data as a struct with several layers, for example:
`data.A.B`
The data I want to access is in layer `B`. But the problem is that field names in `B` can be different depending on where the data comes from. Therefore I can't just type:
`data.A.B.myData`
`myData` is itself a `struct`

I can use:
`fieldnames(data.A)`
to find the names, but this doesn't help my much. I would have to write code sections for every possible field name that can occur at this level. And that's just what i trying to avoid.

Is there a way to get down to the data I have (`myData`) without knowing the field names of `B`?

Comment: Do you need to handle the cases of non-scalar sub-structs and/or multiple instances of `myData` field in different branches of the struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, you can loop over the `fieldnames` and perform the search of `myData` at a specific sub-structure of the struct. However, if you don't know which sub-structure you need to search, then you can perform a recursive algorithm. Below is an example. It will return the first match of `myData` in the struct or an empty matrix if no match found. The code can be improved to find all matches of `myData`.

```
function S2=getmyfield(S1,queriedField)

if isstruct(S1)
    % Get all fieldnames of S1
    fieldArray=fieldnames(S1);

    % Find any match with the queried field. You can also use isfield().
    % If there is a match return the value of S1.(queriedField),
    % else perform a loop and recurse this function.
    matchTF=strcmp(queriedField,fieldArray);
    if any(matchTF)
        S2=S1.(fieldArray{matchTF});
        return;
    else
        S2=[];
        i=0; % an iterator count
        while isempty(S2)
            i=i+1;
            S2=getmyfield(S1.(fieldArray{i}),queriedField);
        end
    end
else
    S2=[];
end

end
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a recursive function that checks fieldnames at each level for the structure.
This is roughly what you need (it could be improved to supply the path to the found field).

```
function [ value, found ] = FindField( rootStruct, fieldName )
%FindField - Find a field with a structure
    value = [];
    found = 0;
    if isstruct( rootStruct )
        fields = fieldnames(rootStruct);
        for fi=1:length(fields)
            if strcmp(fields{fi}, fieldName )
                value = rootStruct.(fieldName);
                found = true;
                return;
            end
            [value, found ] = FindField( rootStruct.(fields{fi}), fieldName );
            if found
                return;
            end
        end
    end

end
```

Usage example:

```
a.b = 1;
a.b.c = 2;
a.b.d = struct('Index',1,'Special',2);
FindField(a,'d')


ans = 

      Index: 1
    Special: 2
```